# I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error on the postman link

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error even though the postman json file is 3mb.
It was working properly yesterday. The link suddenly started getting an error.
I updated the postman link, but the error continues.
When I run with docker, I get the following error.
Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use the Postman API URL for the collection with an API Key, it's a much more secure and upto date way of getting the same information.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below  given methods to resolve this issue.

1. Check if your FQDN (fully qualified domain name) is resolving correctly by using our DNS test tool.
2. Verify if your server is reachable by using a ping test or traceroute.
   Check your firewall logs if you are seeing unusual drops.
3. If you're a Cloudflare user, try disabling it as once you've reached a certain limit Cloudflare will return a 502 Bad Gateway error to your visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I´m having the same issue today.
By the moment, we have fixed by using the link "https://app.getpostman.com/api/collections/XXXXXXXXXXX"  instead of "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/XXXXXXXXXXX"
(being XXXXXXXXXXX the id of your collection)

Answer (score -1):

Check if the port you are querying is already in use or not.